# Examples where customized vector Google Maps rendered via WebGL are used?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, rendering, webgl

Some of the new features are exciting in Google Maps. Creating custom map layers in the cloud and specifically rendering vector maps in WebGL.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-new-maps-customization-features

Do you have real-world examples where I can see this in action?

Comment: Why don't just go through the examples? This one shows the usage of a static IMG to speed the perceived response time to interaction https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/vector-use-static-map

Comment: I would like to look at real-world implementations - do inspect element, run page speed, lighthouse tests to understand speed and performance.

Comment: Because it seeks a list as an answer. In this case a list of real-world examples.